# Javascript eval() output to DOM(HTML)

Tags: javascript, dom

I would like to pass some string into the eval() function in javascript and have it be output as a DOM element in HTML. Is that possible? Currently eval() just outputs to console.

Comment: `someElement.innerHTML = eval(blah)`?

Comment: just posts undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the responses! I was actually able to solve this as follows:

```
const evaluatedCode = document.getElementById("evaluatedCode");
const message = document.getElementById("message");

//basically this code here allowed me to log the console output into a DOM element
var former = console.log;
  console.log = function (msg) {
    former(msg);
    evaluatedCode.append(msg);
  };
  let answer = eval(message.value);
  console.log("", answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code demonstrates that if you try to 'write' an `eval` function anywhere, it will return a string corresponding to the truthfulness of the statement.

In the below code, `eval` gets set as the innerHTML of an element, based on what text is in that element. This reads as the text `true` being written to the element's innerHTML

```js
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = eval(document.getElementById("text").innerHTML.includes("This"));
```

```html
<body>
<div id="main" style="background-color:red;padding:10%;">
  <div id="text" style="background-color:orange;height:50%">
    This
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, let's say i wanted to pass the following into ```eval(const array = [1,2,3];
array.push(4);
console.log(array);)```
I would like to output [1,2,3,4] in the DOM element. However, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Bixar The thing is you need to have a binary statement inside the `eval` statement for it to return a value.
In your example above, you are not comparing anything, but are instead makign an array and then printing that array. `eval` is looking for a statement to return whether it is true or false

Comment: @Bixar in that case, I would make the array in one line, push '4' in the next, and set the DOM element's innerHTML value to be the array on line 3